Correlation between similar time-series (breakthroughcurves)
first of as a disclaimer - I don't have much background, and only a very basic education when it comes to statistics.
I have a couple of break through curves (BTCs) with different tracers and I want to compare them with each other.
Qualitatively the BTCs of NaCl are very similar, almost equivalent. The ones with MX-80 are also very similar to each other, though the red and blue BTC (MX-80 Komp) are a little delayed. I now want to express that in numbers. I tried Pearson correlation, correlating every  single BTC with every other BTC, but that gives really high correlation indices (r) very close to 1 for all compared pairs. Better comparison is possible if I compare the -log(1-r), as in the second picture (which shows the correlation between BTCs from another experiment).
Is there any other good way to quantitatively compare the BTCs?



Anyone got any hints?
